# How to load new cache after content updates in HTML JS?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I am making my first PWA. It works great and as expected untill I tried to make it work offline.

I am using service worker

```js
var cacheName = 'v1'; 
var cacheFiles = [
    'index.html',
    'gallery.html'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
            console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching cacheFiles');
            return cache.addAll(cacheFiles);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
            return Promise.all(cacheNames.map(function(thisCacheName) {
                if (thisCacheName !== cacheName) {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing Cached Files from Cache - ', thisCacheName);
                    return caches.delete(thisCacheName);
                }
            }));
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
            if ( response ) return response
            return  fetch(event.request)
        })
    );
});
```

Could anyone tell me if this is okay. Or if you have any resources for this I would gladly read and learn it.

Problem is that files are cached but everytime I make change I need to clear cache for updates to work. Any ideas how can this be bypassed or fixed?

Or is it even possible to make it work totally offline?

Comment: workbox provides a lot of options, you can start there rather than reimplementation

Comment: Oh thanks for that. I will start with it and after learning some things I might get with my own. *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is useful to know how Service Workers work, you might want to start at higher level, using library like [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/get-started). It will help you quickly set up Service Workers for common use cases.

In your example, you might want to use "[Network or Cache](https://serviceworke.rs/strategy-network-or-cache_service-worker_doc.html)" caching strategy. If network is available try downloading most recent version of files from server, otherwise - fallback to cache. This will let your app work offline.